# Safari 13+ blocks popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, browser, safari

I've just found out that there is a problem with opening popups within Safari `13+`. A long time this little hack worked:

```
let tab = window.open();
tab.location.href = "https://www.google.de";
```

But now the blocker seems to block this also. Can someone approve this? It worked in older versions before. Maybe there is a new and better way to handle this? I need to do this to let my customer pay in a new tab while the source tab polls the payment status.

Comment: Okay so it looks like that I'm the only one because nobody else is commenting here. I'll try to find out why and post an answer. Maybe some of you are noticing it later.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I done it.

```
 var html = '<form style="display:none;" id="safari_fix_form" method="post" target="NewWindow" action="Add Path here..." >\
             <input type = "text" value = "test_param" name = "name" id = "id" />\
             <input type="submit" value="post"> </form>';

 var win = window.open('', 'NewWindow');
 $(html).appendTo('body').submit();
```

In my case I also had to post some parameters to new tab. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Mhm I've did a check and display a popup instead.